# Montar função recursiva para TreeTable

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, recursão

Estou tentando montar uma árvore de pastas e perguntas com Java, Jsf e Primefaces.
Possuo duas listas, uma é a que grava as pastas e subpastas, e outra lista é a que monta as perguntas destas pastas ou subpastas. Segue imagem de como esta montado ate o momento.  [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na pasta que esta ali fora, caso seja selecionado, a pasta é gravada na raiz, conforme mostra a image. Na coluna ações possuo outro icone pasta, e um icone de interrogação que caso seja clicado é adicionado uma pergunta dentro da linha que foi clicada.Segue métodos que consegui montar ate o momento para montar a recursão. Se alguem puder dar uma luz de como montar ficaria grato.

```
public TreeNode montaTreeNode() {

    TreeNode pasta = null;
    TreeNode root = new DefaultTreeNode(new BancoPerguntaView(null, null, null), null);

    if(this.listaBancoPasta != null || !this.listaBancoPasta.isEmpty()){

        try {

            for (BancoPastas bdPasta : this.listaBancoPasta) {

                pasta = new DefaultTreeNode(new BancoPerguntaView(bdPasta.getIdBancoPasta(), bdPasta.getNomePasta(), bdPasta.getTipoPasta()), root);

                this.adicionarFilhos(pasta, bdPasta, null);

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Erro treeNode: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    return root;
}

public void adicionarFilhos(TreeNode nodePai, BancoPastas bdPasta, BancoPerguntas pergunta) {

    if(this.listaBancoPerguntas!= null || !this.listaBancoPerguntas.isEmpty()){

        try {

            for (BancoPerguntas bdPergunta : this.listaBancoPerguntas) {

                TreeNode nodeFilho = new DefaultTreeNode(new BancoPerguntaView(bdPergunta.getFkIdPasta(), bdPergunta.getNomePergunta(), bdPergunta.getTipoPergunta()), nodePai);

                this.adicionarFilhos(nodeFilho, null , bdPergunta);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Erro adicionarFilhos: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Porem quando clico para adicionar uma subpasta ou uma pergunta, entra em loop na linha que chama a recursao

```
this.adicionarFilhos(nodeFilho, null , bdPergunta);
```

Subpastas indo para a raiz, ao inves de entrar na pasta mae

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue metodos refatorados conforme sugestao do Weslley

```
public TreeNode montaTreeNode() {

    TreeNode pasta = null;
    TreeNode root = new DefaultTreeNode(new BancoPerguntaView(null, null, null), null);

    if (this.listaBancoPasta != null || !this.listaBancoPasta.isEmpty()) {

        try {

            for (BancoPastas bdPasta : this.listaBancoPasta) {

                pasta = new DefaultTreeNode(new BancoPerguntaView(bdPasta.getIdBancoPasta(), bdPasta.getNomePasta(), bdPasta.getTipoPasta()), root);

                this.adicionarFilhos(pasta, bdPasta, null);

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Erro treeNode: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    return root;

}

public void adicionarFilhos(TreeNode nodePai, BancoPastas bdPasta, List<BancoPerguntas> perguntas) {

    if (Objects.nonNull(perguntas) && !perguntas.isEmpty()) {

        BancoPerguntas bdPergunta = perguntas.get(0);

        perguntas.remove(bdPergunta); 

        for (BancoPerguntas pergunta : perguntas) {

            TreeNode nodeFilho = new DefaultTreeNode(new BancoPerguntaView(pergunta.getFkIdPasta(), pergunta.getNomePergunta(), pergunta.getTipoPergunta()), nodePai);

            this.adicionarFilhos(nodeFilho, null, perguntas);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

O seu problema está ocorrendo por conta da utilização do parâmetro `listaBancoPerguntas` no seu `for`.

Perceba que toda vez que entrar na chamada do trecho:

```
for (BancoPerguntas bdPergunta : this.listaBancoPerguntas) {
    TreeNode nodeFilho = new DefaultTreeNode(new BancoPerguntaView(bdPergunta.getFkIdPasta(), bdPergunta.getNomePergunta(), bdPergunta.getTipoPergunta()), nodePai);
    this.adicionarFilhos(nodeFilho, null , bdPergunta);
}
```

o seu código irá retornar para o mesmo estado anterior, uma vez que a lista não sofreu nenhuma alteração ainda.

Uma das soluções possíveis seria passar a própria lista como parâmetro para a chamada do seu método `adicionarFilhos()` e realizar a validação (remoção do registro corrente talvez?) necessária para eliminar o *loop* infinito no seu código.

**Proposta de correção**

Uma possibilidade seria refatorar o seu método para:

```
public void adicionarFilhos(TreeNode nodePai, BancoPastas bdPasta, List<BancoPerguntas> perguntas) {
    if (Objects.nonNull(perguntas) && !perguntas.isEmpty()) {
        BancoPerguntas bdPergunta = perguntas.get(0);
        perguntas.remove(bdPergunta); // Assumindo que a classe BancoPerguntas implementa o equals(). Caso não implemente, utilize o índice, que será o 0
        for (BancoPerguntas bdPergunta : perguntas) {
            TreeNode nodeFilho = new DefaultTreeNode(new BancoPerguntaView(bdPergunta.getFkIdPasta(), bdPergunta.getNomePergunta(), bdPergunta.getTipoPergunta()), nodePai);
            this.adicionarFilhos(nodeFilho, null , perguntas);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Weslley, passando como parametro a lista inteira voce diz? ou somente bdPergunta  que é a opção do momento? e a validação que voce esta falando é verificar o que exatamente?

Comment: O seu problema está em utilizar a lista `listaBancoPerguntas` como parâmetro no seu laço de repetição. Note que se você utiliza um parâmetro da classe dentro de um método recursivo e utiliza este atributo para controle na sua recursão, a probabilidade de loop infinito é enorme (que é o seu caso). Para evitar este comportamento, o seu método `adicionarFilhos()` deve utilizar um parâmetro que seja de domínio do próprio método. E a validação seria relacionada ao estado atual da sua implementação, uma vez que em momento algum a lista sofre alteração (uma remoção, por exemplo).

Comment: Editei a resposta para incluir uma proposta de correção. Resolve o problema com o *loop*, agora precisa validar se está adequada a sua regra de negócio.

Comment: Weslley, refatorei o codigo conforme sua indicação. Ao adicionar uma pasta na raiz, esta adicionando corretamente, porem ao tentar adicionar uma subpasta, ele vai para a raiz, e nao para dentro da pasta mae. Editei a publicação colocando as modificações conforme voce indicou. Detalhe que se eu tento adicionar uma pergunta, nao esta tendo ação alguma, e nao gera nenhum erro tambem

Comment: Agora fica um pouco mais complexo de ajudar, uma vez que não consigo simular o cenário sem todo o fluxo da sua aplicação. Outra coisa que me deixou curioso foi o uso do parâmetro `BancoPastas bdPasta` no seu método `adicionarFilhos`, sendo que o mesmo não tem função alguma no trecho.